# Find and rename files removing suffix

Tags: linux, find, rename

I'm using the following command to move all files (non-recursively) ended in **_128.jpg** into the **128x160** subdir. This works great.

```
find . -iname '*_128.jpg' | xargs -I '{}' mv {} 128x160
```

But I also need to remove the **_128** suffix from each file. Also, I must keep my current **xargs** method, making an **exec** for each would make the process extremely longer.

Thanks in advance for your cooperation!

Comment: Is this really faster than using exec? I believe it would be faster if you used `find ..... | xargs mv -t 128x160` because in that case it would move as many files it could with one `mv` command. The way you call it it runs `mv` as many times as there are files to be moved. Compare `find . -iname '*_128.jpg' | xargs -I '@' echo @ bla` to `find . -iname '*_128.jpg' | xargs echo bla`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick :

```
find . -iname '*_128.jpg' | xargs -I % sh -c 'newname=$(echo % | sed "s/_128//"); mv % 128x160/$newname'
```

Here i have used a multiple commands approach using `sh -c 'command1; command2'` and `sed` to clear `_128` in the filename.